# Azure App Service Continuous Deployment with VSTS

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have set up Azure continuous deployment from a branch in my Visual Studio Team Services GIT Repository. Everything is working fine however I would like to run a few gulp tasks before the actual deployment takes place. Is there a way how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

`Azure` provides `continuous deployment` out of the box through the use of several sources of your code. What you will need will be more in the side of `continuous integration`, running tasks and flows to build the code.

There are many ways and tools of doing continuous integration, nevertheless the most compatible to do this in `Azure` would be within the build and release parts of `Visual Studio Team Services`.

Within your `Azure` subscription you can setup this following the next steps(**it seems you have already setup your code in `Visual Studio team services`, then you can skip to step 3**):

1. Creating a `VSTS` project

[image]

2. Putting your code in a `Git` Repo inside `VSTS`

[image]

3. Creating a Build definition

[image]

4. Adding your tasks from the Catalog

[image]

5. Adding and configuring your `Gulp` Tasks

[image]

6. Deploying the build to `Azure`

[image]